# What is the reason of the exception?

Tags: c, windows

Can anyone find out the reason of the error?
The code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    strcat(argv[1], ", Agniva welcomes you");
    printf("%s", argv[1]);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Actually the program will modify the `argv[1]` parameter (which is a name say) which is called by another program as call by reference.

BUT I am getting

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007ffd21d41cd0 in greet.exe: 
0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted.
```

But if I take an extra parameter through command line which is not needed then this error gets vanished. Can you say which is making problem here?

Comment: Welcome to [android.se]! You seem to be confused and lost your way here. That's fine. I've voted to migrate this question to [so], where you'll get professional answers, and it's also the correct place for this question. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @iBug Most people who post programming questions here do so because they're question-banned on SO, which would make the migration fail. Because of that, I don't usually bother trying to migrate unless there's a special reason e.g. someone has already answered here and the answer would be lost if we didn't migrate.

Comment: @DanHulme This one may worth giving it a chance, IMO, given the content quality and the correct formatting that I edited. I'd appreciate it if you do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`strcat(argv[1], ", Agniva welcomes you");`

this is exactly and reason — at first you can access `argv[1]`  only in case:

```
if (argc > 1) // do something with argv[1]
```

at second, even if `argv[1]` point to valid memory block - you simply overwrite it with `strcat` - append data to it. in your concrete case `argv[1]` allocated from heap, and you write to memory block past it size. as result you and got *A heap has been corrupted.*

Comment: While it is good practice to treat argv as read-only, we can actually know that it points at valid read/write memory, since this is guaranteed by the C standard 5.1.2.2.1. So we can write to argv just fine and doing so is well-defined and portable. But we can of course not write out of bounds. So if `argv[n]` is `"hello"` then we can only reliably write up to 5+1=6 characters to that array. Not a good idea, but supported by the C standard.

Comment: @Lundin - yes, you are right. the memory, to which points `argv[i]` of course writable. but rarely exist sense modify it. only one case which i view - uppercase or  lowercase strings, before parsing parameters, if program use case insensitive command line semantic

Answer (score 0):

This is my previous comment on the question, and it's almost a complete answer.

In brief, there's no extra memory space allocated for every item in argv, so when you try to strcat more string onto it, you're writing outside the buffer, which leads to undefined behavior. When you have an extra argument supplied, you're actually writing to the memory where the other argument resides. Again this is implementation-specific, and may still become undefined behavior when you run the program on another platform (like Linux).

Comment: This is mostly a comment on implementation details, not language guarantees. Whether extra memory is allocated for each `argv` entry is private to the implementation. That doesn't make any difference, though. Reading/writing outside the bounds of the array **is** UB, always, irrespective of whether the application fails or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have no way of knowing how much of a memory is allocated for argv[1] yet still trying to stub it with another 20+ bytes.

```
 strcat(argv[1], ", Agniva welcomes you");
```

Perhaps something like this

```
 if( argc < 2 )
        return -1;

    char *oBuf = calloc( strlen( argv[1] ) + 25 /* for this ", Agniva welcomes you" */ , 1);

    sprintf( oBuf, "%s%s",argv[1], ", Agniva welcomes you");
    printf("%s", oBuf);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you . This is very helpful.